# Send data from one site to another

Tags: php, fopen

I have create a script that I like to send some data to another web site. Nothing more than sending that information.

If I use something like that will work for each host ?

```
$f = fopen('http://www.my-web-site.ext/' . $data . '/', 'r');
fclose($f);
```

or will that produce errors ? Have I to make any check before that ?

Comment: you should provide some `$data` insight

Comment: the data is an md5 string. Nothing more. I just like to know if there is any limitation from PHP or PHP Ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem if its MD5 data. But for efficiency I'd advice you to use cURL

http://php.net/curl

Answer (score 1):

From PHP's [fopen](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> If PHP has decided that filename specifies a registered protocol, and
>   that protocol is registered as a network URL, PHP will check to make
>   sure that allow_url_fopen is enabled. If it is switched off, PHP will
>   emit a warning and the fopen call will fail.

So, you should check if [allow_url_fopen](http://br.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is enabled in PHP.ini. One way to check this is through

```
ini_get('allow_url_fopen')
```

If it's 1, you're good to go. Getting 0? Try [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).